# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? (5)

Tags: пунктуация

При выборе партнера в Китае отталкиваться нужно не только от цены, а от совокупности цены и качества (,) и работать только с производителями.

Правильно ли я рассуждаю? Здесь все же простое предложение с основой **нужно отталкиваться и работать**, поэтому **при выборе партнера в Китае** не нужно рассматривать как общий второстепенный член, после противопоставления запятая ставится только перед союзом **а** (?), исходя из всего этого спорная запятая не нужна.

Comment: _Alenka: отталкиваться нужно не только от цены, **а от** совокупности..._  === Замените "а от" на  "но и от".

Comment: Тогда смысл меняется... Ведь цена остается в обоих случаях, поэтому нельзя сказать **не только от цены, но и от цены**... Может быть, можно сказать **не только от цены, но и от качества**...

Comment: Вам пытались сказать, что "не только, но и " - двойной союз, его нельзя заменить на "не только, а", это грамматическая ошибка. Если первый вариант, с А, то "не..., а...", убрать "только".

Comment: При выборе партнера ... работать только с производителями. Как будто производители помогают выбирать партнера(?!).Вы хотели сказать: выбирать партнера только среди призводителей?

Answer (score 1):

Согласна (с учётом исправления НЕ ТОЛЬКО, НО И): При выборе партнера в Китае отталкиваться нужно не только от цены, а от совокупности цены и качества и работать только с производителями.

Но вот рассуждения Ваши не очень поняла.

```
 Здесь все же простое предложение с основой нужно отталкиваться 
 и работать, поэтому при выборе партнера в Китае не нужно рассматривать 
  как общий второстепенный член, после противопоставления запятая 
 только перед союзом а (?), исходя из всего этого спорная запятая не нужна.
```

Нужно отталкиваться  и работать - два однородных сказуемых с пропуском во втором вспомогательного слова, союз И не повторяется. Именно поэтому нет запятой.

Comment: Может быть, тогда **не только от цены, но от совокупности цены и качества**?

Comment: Я просто сначала поверхностно подумала. что это сложносочиненное предложение, а когда увидела, что основа одна, поняла, что запятой не нужно, хотя у меня остаются сомнения, что после такого противопоставления с союзом **а** ставят еще одну запятую... Это неправильно наверное?

Comment: При выборе партнера в Китае отталкиваться нужно не только от цены, но и от совокупности цены и качества и работать только с производителями. Вы так предлагаете?

Comment: Да, так. Теперь всё соблюдено.

Comment: По-моему, смысл очень сильно искажается... Два раза повторяется условие отталкиваться от цены. То есть отталкиваться нужно не только от цены, но и от совокупности цены и качества. Цена противопоставляется ее собственной совокупности  с качеством. Мне это кажется странным.

Comment: Ну так мы-то рассматриваем Ваше предложения, а если править, то проще будет: При выборе партнера в Китае нужно учитывать не только цену, отталкиваться следует  от совокупности цены и качества  и работать только с производителями. Или про цену вообще убрать, и так понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "При выборе партнера .... работать только с производителями"? Только работая с производителями, вы сможете выбрать партнера? Возможно так, но скорее всего, вы хотели сказать, что выбирать партнера нужно только среди прозводителей. В таком случае фразу нужно изменить, например так:

**При выборе партнера в Китае отталкиваться нужно не только от цены, а от совокупности цены и качества и *рассматривать* только производителей.**